# Decompilation Issues

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

i'm new here, so please be more patient :)

Task:
i've decompiled very old app to adopt it for mouse clicking and touch. i've used .NET Reflector 8 for decompilation process. After i've opened solution in VS2013 and tried to debug application, i've dealed with following error:

"Error  1 Use of unassigned local variable 'pass' Form1.cs"

here is code: 
1st error:

```
 foreach (Software.dsBDD.list_table21 row in dataTable.Rows)
 {
            PictureBox box;
            MemoryStream stream;
            Panel panel;
            Label label;
            bool? pass;
            if (this.pass.HasValue && this.end)
    {
    pass = this.pass;
    }
if ((***pass***.GetValueOrDefault() && pass.HasValue) || row.view_only)
}
```

2nd error:

```
    Panel panel = sender as Panel;
    if (panel.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        bool? pass;
        if (this.pass.HasValue && this.end)
        {
            pass = this.pass;
        }
        if ((***pass***.GetValueOrDefault() && pass.HasValue) || this.view_only)
     }
```

(i've marked as ***pass*** the selected error by compiler)

Please suggest what is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: asteriks to left of pass show that its pointer to pointer to pointer but asteriks to right of it indicate what?

Comment: There is actually no guarantee that a decompiled application will compile again to proper executable code.

Comment: i`m very sorry, this is my first question here. asterisks is only for selecting word in code for which error appears while compiling

Comment: @user3560075 I'd be very careful with this. You might have solved the compilation error, but the code doesn't make any sense. `pass` is a local variable and a field - are you sure it's doing what it's supposed to be doing now? And even if it is, consider rewriting the thing to make it clear. It's very confusing, and it's generally a bad practice to use variable names (or parameters) that "hide" fields.

Comment: i`ve compiled and tested application and it works! now, after i have source code i need to "teach" my app to respond to mouseclicks, rather than keyboard inputs... i`ll try to open new question =)

Answer (score 1):

t's because your variable `pass` doesn't have a value assigned.

You can solve this by assigning `null` to your variable.

```
bool? pass = null;
```

Comment: Actually, i don`t know what is "pass" means in this code, but this tiny app is reading username and password from file to access the database.

Comment: @user3560075 I can't tell you that, I don't have your application. But my guess is that it keeps track if the user has filled in a password or that the combination of username and password is correct?

Comment: i`ve made changes and compiler finished w/o ay errors, thanks! it works!!

Comment: Seems this variable should not be null. i`ve examined whole app and found that this part of code is depends on this: "this.qta.(this.q, tag, ref nullable2, ref end, ref this.pass)" and it gets value from "bool? pass;" ... but how to declare it in my "if" statement?

Comment: @Gambarsky Can you edit your question and add the code of that method?

Comment: sorry i`m new here. what exact should i do?

Comment: @Gambarsky You can edit [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23217498/edit) and add the code of this: 'this.qta.(this.q, tag, ref nullable2, ref end, ref this.pass)' and everything that you think is important to solve your new question. :)

Comment: sorry, can you write me an email? i don`t understand what you are talking about. darkdmin=gmail=com